# cant install php55 imagick on centos 6.8 php-devel installed but missing

Tags: php, apache, centos, yum

i´m right about f*ing up my whole running system just for adding imagick to php  so here is where i am at. i want to use yum to install, i have enabled remi55 and loaded all necessary

php version

```
$php -v
PHP 5.5.34 (cli) (built: Mar 29 2016 19:27:57) 
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

gcc is installed

```
Package gcc-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

imagemagick and imagemagick-devel is installed

```
Package ImageMagick-6.7.2.7-6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ImageMagick-devel-6.7.2.7-6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

php-devel seems to be installed

```
Package php55-php-devel-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

even more stuff i installed

```
Package php55-php-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed
php55-php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64 0:2.5.3-2.el6.remi already installed
```

i dont know tryed a lot but when it comes to

```
pecl install imagick
```

i get an error

```
Starting to download imagick-3.4.3.tgz (245,410 bytes)
............................done: 245,410 bytes
19 source files, building
running: phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

so ok, i try to `yum install php-devel` even i know i have php-devel for my php version and i get the following error :

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Removing: php-common-5.5.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Updated By: php-common-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-6.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
           Removing: php-common-5.5.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Updated By: php-common-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-6.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Removing: php-common-5.5.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Updated By: php-common-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-6.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (remi-php55)
           Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
           Removing: php-common-5.5.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Updated By: php-common-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-6.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

so i really go crazy and i dont know what to do now ?! 
the thing i dont want to the the most is "remove all and install from scratch" as i said i got a working system with lots of sites involved, so if you have any idea let me know, sure i tried restarting httpd

i know i probably did not provide all required information but i didnt want to tldr;

after all `php -m | grep image`

returns nothing

heres the full output of php -m

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
recode
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

Comment: `Package php55-php-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed` -- that should do it. Run `php -m` and see if imagick is in the output.

Comment: nope, unfortunatly it is not :*( i added the output of php -m

Comment: Run `rpm -ql php55-php-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64` to get a list of files in that package. One of them should be `imagick.so`

Comment: absolutely right ! it´s at   `/opt/remi/php55/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so`

do i have to  refference this into httpd.conf ?  what would be the exact name like 'LoadModule imagick {path} ' ?

Comment: Make sure your `php.ini` contains `extension = imagick.so`.

Comment: get this error: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: i try to just copy it there

Comment: Make sure the permissions are set so that it's world-readable.

Comment: okay thank you so much, its getting better now, but still got this error `Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1687 but version 1688 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable remi-test (which have some 5.6 packages, so create conflicts).

```
yum-config-manager --disable remi-test
yum install php-pecl-imagick
```

BTW [5.5 is now EOL](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/09/10/PHP-5.5-is-dead), so I strongly recommend you update to a [maintained version](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

php55-php-pecl-imagick is an SCL package for multiple versions installed simultaneously, you probably don't need this.

See the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

Comment: EOL ^^ you´re absolutely right and i thank you for pointing that out, will do so asap. Also i had remi-test enabled so this definetly is the answer to my question. Thanks a lot